# Set workbook name after creating from template with VB6

Tags: vba, vb6

I am creating a workbook from a template with my VB6 program, like this:

```
set myWorkBook = myExcelApp.workbooks.Add(App.path & "\MyTemplate.xlt")
```

This creates a workbook named "MyTemplate1.xls". I would like the workbook name to be more meaningful.

My question is: is there a way to set the name of this just created workbook?

I know I can do this by saving the workbook, but I don't like that solution, I prefer that the user decides if he really wants to keep the file and name it as he wants.

Comment: The only way is by saving the workbook.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a way to set a workbook name using Interop without saving, but given your description the obvious solution is to copy the template file to your new, more meaningful name, before opening it.  This should give you name like Meaning1, not perfect but much closer than mytemplate1...

Answer (score 0):

You could just delete it later if the user decides they don't want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
myWorkBook.SaveAs "AnyFilenameYouWish.xls"
```

The full option to save is:

```
Workbook.SaveAs(FileName,
                FileFormat,
                Password,
                WriteResPassword,
                ReadOnlyRecommended,
                CreateBackup,
                AccessMode,
                ConflictResolution,
                AddToMru,
                TextCodepage,
                TextVisualLayout,
                Local)
```

Comment: Note: question is 18 months old.